# Where to host a Ruby app which uses websockets via faye?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, thin, faye

- No `websockets` on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/),
- no `thin` on [Engineyard](http://www.engineyard.com/),
- gave [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/) a try, but they are quite far from being ready for production.

If I want to host a Ruby/Rails app which uses `websockets` via `faye`, where can I do that?

Comment: I've gotten Faye up and running pretty well under OpenShift using the DIY (the only way to get websockets going ATM.) Not exactly trivial, but hey -- free Faye in the cloud.

Comment: @JosephWeissman if you're willing to post a some more detailed steps of the working solution, for future reference, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Went ahead and pushed my working 'pristine' repo up to Github :) I've put the link into an answer and added some notes, but no need to accept unless it actually helps you...

Comment: @JosephWeissman it sure helps!

Comment: Heroku supports websockets now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku now supports WebSockets (finally!): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to spend, but your best option is proably going to be looking into a VPS hosting solution, such as [Linode](http://www.linode.com/).  This way you have the freedom to install the software that you need.

**Edit:** (based on your comment)
You could also try [the free tier of Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) but you only get one year of free service.

Comment: I'm looking into spending as little as possible, maybe get even in a free tier. I find it hard to believe there is no Paas offer around to match that.

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own vserver, costs just a few bucks nowadays. You can run there everything you want and have full control over it.

Comment: Thats quite the best answer. There are a several companies where u can rent a vserver. I can get u a free month at www.zertico.com so u can give it a shot! =p

Answer (score 0):

There's a company called Blue Box in Seattle you might look into.

I work there, so there's that shameless plug aspect going on. But I think they'll be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example OpenShift DIY instance](https://github.com/jweissman/zephyr-faye-diy) that's currently running a prod Faye instance in the cloud for me.

As you say, OpenShift isn't really ready for primetime -- so I'm actually talking to this box from my main app running on Heroku! One note here might be that websockets secure protocol (wss) is supported on 8443 for OpenShift.

Comment: Note that Heroku supports websockets now, so there's that.